# Unpause a rails server that was paused in a different terminal window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

I'm on mac osx using zsh. If I start a rails server with "rails s" I can put it in the background by hitting "ctrl-z" in my terminal (zsh). I can restart it with "fg".

If I open up a different terminal window then I don't see the rails server if I do "jobs". However, I can see it when I do "ps".

Is there a way I can somehow "unpause" the rails server in this new terminal window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, find out the process number of the rails process, then send it the continue signal using kill(1).

`$> kill -s CONT pid`

Comment: Where `pid` is the process id, obviously. Your `kill` command might have different syntax, if the above doesn't work, try `man kill` on your system.

Comment: I don't know why but it's not working. I do `kill -l` to list the commands and I see CONT. So I try `kill -CONT 88402` and then I just see a new terminal prompt...nothing seems to happen.

Comment: You wouldn't see the process' output in the terminal you're sending the continue signal from, it would still go to the terminal that the process was originally attached to.

Comment: To be able to attach and detach to processes (and watch their output, etc.) you should be using [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), it's available for almost all unix-like os:es.

Comment: @uvesten could I use tmux in the same way as screen?

Comment: dunno, have never used tmux.